# Cycles bump node behaves weirdly non-linear. Is there something wrong with its implementation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, bump

Cycles and Eevee don't agree, and I think Cycles' implementation of the bump node is wrong. Where do I go to report this?

This is why I think so:

I made a tool that "carves" a bump map I want to use. The shape is like a V, it's a linear gradient from black to white. Imagine it like a tool bit. See example:

[image: V-carve]

This works well and it looks correct in Blender (I make sure to use the "Non-Color" setting):
[image: nodes and render]

But now I try to use nodes to soften this shape, to ease into the transition, and give it rounded edges, like so:

[image: rounded carve]

To do so, I transform the bump map with a curve (I've tried vector and RGB curves, they behave about the same). The result is hard to achieve and shows aliasing, but looks OK in Eevee, see here:

[image]

Now compare this to Cycles, where it doesn't work:

[image]

No matter what I do, I can't get the peaks and valleys to curve smoothly like I can in Eevee.

***Edit***

Here with a much lower bump value, the sides are still much more straight than expected:

[image: unexpected linear sides]

Interestingly, at lower bump values the difference between Eevee and Cycles disappears.

If you want to try this yourself, here's the 16-bit grayscale Tiff:
[out-cone511d.tif](https://jacobbruinsma.com/resources/out-cone511d.tif)

Comment: It'd be really surprising if your model was scaled such that a 1.0 distance on the bump node was appropriate.  Take a look at using the bump map as displacement on a subdivided model instead-- the scale appropriate for displacement should be the distance you use for the bump.  It's measured in Blender units.  I suspect you're just giving crazy high levels of bump and Eevee's limited bump mapping is covering up the problems more than Cycles.

Comment: @Nathan is right :). The bump Distance is in meters. To get useful result, try lowering the distance value (0.001 for milimeters)

Comment: 1.0 is excessive, but for this application I want the extremes to be handled correctly. I'll edit my post and show a lesser bump, showing the sides are barely curved, whereas my curve looks like it would apply more distortion. The curve isn't softening the bump enough.

Comment: Have the same problem, did you find a way to smooth bump in cycles? eevee: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rxyj.png, cycles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNUj7.png

Comment: @kitbukoros I haven't tried it since this post, but if you're having the same problem, I guess that means it hasn't been resolved. It sounds like a bug in the shader, to me, so I suppose we could report it.